# Set PointSize to pixel size

Tags: graphics, image

I have a set of 1million 2D points and I would like to produce an image 200x200 pixels where each point will have the size of a pixel (no more).
Additionally each point may repeats several times so I would like to add some weight on it (small number of repetitions ->Light Green , ... , large number of repetitions ->Dark Green)

I am experimenting with the following data set before I use the real one :

```
data = Flatten[
   Table[Table[{i, j} k, {i, 1, 50}, {j, 1, 50}], {k, 1, 10, .5}], 2];
```

So which is the correct PointSize in my case and how can I set the intensity of each point ?

I am not that experienced on Graphics so I would appreciate any insight.

Comment: PointeSize[0] is valid ?

Comment: For the intensity, you could use different `Opacity` values for a given color or overlay several points with constant `Opacity`.

Comment: Thank you @YvesKlett how can I overlay the points?

Comment: Try this line to get an idea: `Graphics[{PointSize[Large], 
  Point[#[[1 ;; 2]], 
     VertexColors -> Directive[Opacity[#[[3]]], Blue]] & /@ 
   RandomReal[{0, 1}, {3000, 4}]}]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
data = Flatten[
   Table[Table[{i, j} k, {i, 1, 50, .3}, {j, 1, 50, .3}], {k, 1, 
     10, .3}], 2];
Dimensions@data (*{833776, 2}*)
```

You can also do something like: (*here I've assumed that you know what is the range of the data - 500*)

```
m = SparseArray[Rule[IntegerPart[#], #2
                    ] & @@@ Tally[(200. Round[data/500., 1/200.] + 1.)]];

ArrayPlot[m, PlotRangePadding -> 0, ImageSize -> {200, 200}, Frame -> False,
             ColorFunction -> (Blend[{LightGreen, Darker@Green}, #] &)]
```

> [image]

Comment: With `DensityHistogram` there's no need to generate `m`:

`DensityHistogram[
 data, PlotRangePadding -> 0,
 ImageSize -> {200, 200}, Frame -> False,
 ColorFunction -> (Blend[{LightGreen, Darker@Green}, #] &),
 PerformanceGoal :> "Speed"
 ]`

Comment: @ArgentoSapiens Good point, you can post an answer. It calculates quite a long time though.

Answer (score 3):

To answer the question of how to set the point size to precisely one pixel: use `AbsolutePointSize[1]`.

[`PointSize`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/PointSize.html) specifies the point diameter relative to the graphics width.  Points whose size is controlled by this directive change size when the graphics is resized.

[`AbsolutePointSize`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/AbsolutePointSize.html) will use [printer's points](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PostScript_point) for printable vector graphics (such as PDF) and pixels for on-screen display.  `AbsolutePointSize[1]` will always display with a diameter of 1 pixel, regardless of the screen resolution.  (This is not what the docs say, but this is what happens.  The point-to-pixel ratio might be adjustable somewhere in the option inspector, not sure about this.  By default it's 1, i.e. 72 "dpi".)  When using `AbsolutePointSize`, the point size will be independent of the graphics size.

Comment: +1 Thanks @Szabolics I didn't suspect that.